# TypeORM with multiple env setups

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I want to use a separate database for running tests. So I tried to configure TypeORM for multiple environments (dev and test) but it's not working. It only use the 'dev' configuration.

This is my npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=dev node dist/index.js",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --reporter spec --compilers ts:ts-node/register 'test/**/*.test.ts'"
}
```

If I `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` I get the correct results ("dev" / "test").

This is my `ormconfig.json`

```
[
  {
    "environment": "dev",
    "name": "default",
    "driver": {
      "type": "mysql",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 3306,
      "username": "root",
      "password": "",
      "database": "api"
    },
    "entities": [ "dist/model/*.js" ],
    "autoSchemaSync": true
  },
  {
    "environment": "test",
    "name": "default",
    "driver": {
      "type": "mysql",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 3306,
      "username": "root",
      "password": "",
      "database": "api_test"
    },
    "entities": [ "dist/model/*.js" ],
    "autoSchemaSync": true
  }
]
```

I connect with `createConnection();`. I manually created both databases `api` and `api_test` beforehand.

**Why is TypeORM not using the "test" configuration when I set NODE_ENV=test?**

Answer (score 12):

You could change your `ormconfig.json` to a `js` file then do something similar to this:

```
require('dotenv/config');


const database = {
  development: "dev-db",
  production: 'prod-db',
  test: 'test-db'
}

module.exports = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'ur-username',
  password: 'password',
  database: database[process.env.NODE_ENV],
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
  migrationsTableName: 'migration',
  migrations: ['migration/*.js'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'migration',
  },
};
```

Then when running your tests, don't forget to set the appropriate environment. `NODE_ENV=test` should do.

Comment: it is safe to have this info in a .json or .js?? I am stuck trying to change fron .json to .env, can I leave it on .json with no problem??

Comment: @sgClaudia98 did you find an answer ?

Comment: @Alexy I leave it in .json, it was the same

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. I got this to work by using different 'name' fields for each connection.  For my run-time connection, I kept `name=default`, and for my test connection I used `name=test`. So:

```
[
  {
    "environment": "dev",
    "name": "default",
    "driver": {
      "type": "mysql",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 3306,
      "username": "root",
      "password": "",
      "database": "api"
    },
    "entities": [ "dist/model/*.js" ],
    "autoSchemaSync": true
  },
  {
    "environment": "test",
    "name": "test",          //// CHANGED
    "driver": {
      "type": "mysql",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 3306,
      "username": "root",
      "password": "",
      "database": "api_test"
    },
    "entities": [ "dist/model/*.js" ],
    "autoSchemaSync": true
  }
]
```

In my application, I would simply use `createConnection()`, which would automatically use the connection with `name=default`.

For my tests, I used typeorm's `createConnections()` (notice the s). This loads all connections. Once loaded, I would immediately after use `getConnection('test')`, which would get the test connection.  My `beforeAll` in my tests looked like this in typescript:

```
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await createConnections();
    getConnection('test');
  });
```

In javascript, it would probably look something like:

```
  beforeAll(() => {
    createConnections().then(() => {
        getConnection('test');
    });
  });
```

Then my tests started to pass. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by installing cross-env and the dotenv-flow package.

My typeorm script looked like this:

```
"typeorm": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d src/core/database/ormconfig.ts",
```

And I created an ormconfig.ts file, where I define the database connection variables through process.env, and all I had to do was add the "require" related to "dotenv-flow".

My ormconfig.ts

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
require('dotenv-flow').config();

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT) || 5432,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    entities: [
    ],
    migrations: [
    ],
    migrationsRun: false,
    migrationsTableName: 'history'
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

This option is no longer available.

You can see the pull request that removed it from the TypeORM docs, in Aug, 2017, here:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm.github.io/pull/13/files

The functionality itself seems to have been removed in a [commit](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/commit/0f8b4debe59232411cd30a691c8051107a911b9b) with other changes to fix another (unrelated?) issue. It is not immediately clear what the intent was in removing it.

Comment: expand on the answer

Comment: Link only answers are a bad idea - if the content of the page you reference changes or the page is moved your answer becomes meaningless